# Ubuntu-Sdk Design Mode Error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I have a problem opening up design mode in the Ubuntu-Sdk. I get an error reading typinfo files. I have ubuntu-sdk installed on Ubuntu 14.10.

Am I missing a package?

Here is a screen capture of the design mode error:

[image: screenshot of design mode error]

Also, here is an import error that is probably related:

[image: probably related import error]

`tail -n 1000000 $(ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components | grep -v *.so)`: [pastebin.ubuntu.com/10314503/](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10314503/)

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file that is mentioned in the error with sudo rights.
And you should replace all of these:

```
exports: ["UbuntuColors -1.-1"]
exportMetaObjectRevisions: [-1]
```

With something like this:

```
exports: ["UbuntuColors 1.1"]
exportMetaObjectRevisions: [1]
```

Save the file and restart qt creator.

Comment: this worked on any off you??

Comment: It worked for me,but it is a bit hit and miss. Sometimes I have to try things around. I got this same advice from others on AskUbuntu and it worked for them.